# Programmatically create large PNG based on smaller PNG in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, image, image-processing

I'm trying to programatically create a large PNG based on a smaller PNG in Objective-C. The smaller PNG is a logo that I'm using as a watermark. I want to place the smaller PNG in the lower right corner of the large PNG. The large PNG should be the size of the source video and has a transparent background.

I have this working in C# but can't quite figure out how to get working in Objective-C. I think I should be using the Image I/O libraries.

```
Bitmap bm;
int shortestSide;
if (videoWidth > videoHeight)
    shortestSide = videoHeight;
else
    shortestSide = videoWidth;

var logoDimension = (int)(shortestSide * 0.05);

Image logo;
if (logoDimension <= 16)
    logo = Resources.watermark_16x16;
else if (logoDimension <= 24)
    logo = Resources.watermark_24x24;
else if (logoDimension <= 36)
     logo = Resources.watermark_36x36;
else if (logoDimension <= 48)
     logo = Resources.watermark_48x48;
else if (logoDimension <= 54)
     logo = Resources.watermark_54x54;
else
     logo = Resources.watermark_64x64;

var logoPoint = new Point(videoWidth - logo.Width * 2, videoHeight - logo.Height * 2);

var image = new Bitmap(videoWidth, videoHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    g.DrawImageUnscaled(logo, logoPoint);
}

bm = image;
bm.Save(watermarkPath, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know any Objective-C? Have you used Cocoa or Foundation before? The languages and the frameworks are different so you probably shouldn't try to port this code directly.

Comment: but you know, that Objective-C isn't C#?

Comment: Yes I know Objective-C isn't C#. I've used it for several months. I posted my C# so people could see what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish the same task in Objective-C.

Comment: You should show, what you have tried in Objective-C. Stackoverflow surely isn't a translation engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to a blog post I wrote for merging images.  This is a UIImage category that overlays (or underlays) a passed in image to the existing UIImage.

http://saveme-dot-txt.blogspot.com/2011/06/merge-image-function.html

basically the key is to create a new image context, draw your first image onto it, then your second, and then return the new image.

After you have the new image, I think you can do something like:

```
   NSData *dataForPNGFile = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);
```

to get the PNG encoding.